# What's the best way to insert a base64 image to MySQL database via cors? (MySQL+Express+React+Node stack)

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, reactjs, express

I am capturing a base64 image into React state and would like to insert it to mySQL database so i can utilise this as the profile picture later on. I am currently using `fetch` to insert data within the MERN stack (MySQL+Express+React+Node) but it generates 400 bad request when I try insert the image with {mode : 'no-cors'} and header missing error when not using 'no-cors'.

Comment: better to save image to physical directory and path to the database. it will help data bandwidth and performance.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I need to save the base64 string to the database so the image can be retrieved from any location. Any tips?

Comment: @asimshahiddIT what do you think the best way for this is?

Comment: as base64 in db take lots of space, even some big image in base64 can't be save in single insert

Comment: So if saving locally into the file system is not an option, how do i go about this?